# WSO2 Dashboard SAML auth: PKIX path building failed

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0, jaggery-js, pkix, wso2-identity-server

Using the wso2 identity server in my on production site I try to access to "dashboard jaggery apps" for manage own user account (change password, etc). But when I try to login in there (using SAML2 in the https production domain) shows the following error,

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

We write the keystore path in the `auth_config.json` inside `repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/dashboard/authentication`, but it does not work. 
We have other application using the same fingerprint and/or x.509 hash correctly (with SAML2), but this app we can't configure.

here the complete error http://pastebin.com/tgJenydM

Any suggestions? Thanks.

---

update:

When I use the backend IP the error is not raised, but when I change to the domain name yes. (This error really make me crazy)

Answer (score 1):

Did you change the default keystore of WSO2IS server ? If, Could you pleas let us know whether you import your new certificate in to the trust store file (`client-truststore.jks`) of WSO2IS server. If it is not, This can be the issue. Please export the certificate from Keystore and import it in to the trust store of the server.  You can use jave `keytool` command to do it.

When you are working on dashboard (not in localhost), there are some few configuration you need to do . You can find them from [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2544)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I imported the certificate in to the trust store file (`client-truststore.jks`) and change the localhost name into the gadgets file, etc. following the jira mention.
I have noticed that the following message is displayed on the site in production but not so when using localhost 
`INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} -  Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://sso.jfwebportal.com:443/services/SAML2SSOAuthenticationService] `

Comment: Can this be? How could I fix it?